# PHP MySQL Ajax insert - when to use?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

this question is not really a 'show me the problem' kind of questions, but rather one that puts emphasis on the best practice / what to avoid.

I'm building a PHP driven site with certain number of javascript / ajax calls. Few things I'm curious about are:

- does it make sense to use ajax when inserting data into the database?
- is there any visible advantage (does it make the site more user-friendly)?

If I decide to implement DB inserts with Ajax, I'd like to know what people think is the best practice in terms of site refresh. Let's assume I have a code similar to this:

```
<div>some data</div>
<form><input type="button" onclick="javascript:AjaxInsert()">some form</form>
```

When the user submits the form, Ajax function is called and some PHP code is run on the server side. PHP script inserts data into the DB and:

- I can build the content of the div with data in the PHP script and pass it back to the original site

Is this something people would recommend? I found lot of examples here and elsewhere but majority of them uses jquery. I may be weird that way but I prefer not to use any extra libraries (like jquery).

Comment: don't use ajax just because its the new and shiny new thing

Comment: I recommend from experience to only use ajax as it enhances the site and not just because you can. For example if the inserted data needs to be displayed then go easy on yourself and reload the page and insert and select new content.

Comment: @Dagon I know - I don't intend to use ajax just 'because it's new and shiny' (it's hardly anything new anyway) but if I do opt to use ajax I want it to be beneficial to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say use it for inserts when you want real-time updates as well. Such as Twitter, Facebook, etc.